# Special characters for column labels in correlation matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I ran into an issue, running the ggcorr package.
My dataframe is quite simple, but column labels contain special characters:

| SAPS | e' | E/e' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 11,9 | 5,0 |
| 14 | 6,2 | 11,1 |
| 14 | 7,4 | 8,2 |
| 15 | 7,5 | 6,8 |
| 14 | 11,1 | 7,8 |
| 13 | 6,6 | 10,5 |
| 14 | 10,2 | 6,0 |
| 13 | 7,1 | 9,1 |
| 12 | 10,0 | 6,1 |
| 15 | 10,8 | 4,9 |

When I run the code as is, the output does not label correctly the variables.
I wish to transpose the column names as is.
[In this example, the figure says e. instead of e' and E.e. instead of E/e'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxsrO.png)

How should I do it?
Thank you in advance,

```
ggcorr(ex_db, nbreaks = 4,
        label = TRUE,
        label_size = 3,
        method = c("pairwise", "spearman"))
```

I tried
 `ggcorr(ex_db, aes(x, y=c(`SAPS`,` e'`,` E/e'`)), method = c("pairwise", "spearman")) + geom_point()` 
without success

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Thank you, I just added a fake table which contains the true column names I wish to use, so you can see they contain special characters (here: / and ')

Comment: Thanks for providing the data. Just as a reminder for the future. You could share your data more easily using the `dput()` function which allows to share data as "code" in a reproducible way, e.g. `dput(ex_db[1:10, ])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This look like a bug. I had a look at the source code of `GGally::ggcorr`.

The issue is that your column names are not "syntactically valid variable" names. And unfortunately `ggcorr` converts the correlation matrix to a dataframe using `data.frame()` with the default `check.names=TRUE`.

As a result the column names are converted to syntactically valid names, thereby replacing the "special" symbols by dots.

A "hacky" workaround (which may not work in general) would be to manipulate the `ggplot` object returned by `ggcorr` and replacing the `diagLabel` column containing the labels with the original column names.

Note: This requires to identify the correct `geom_text` layer which adds the labels stored in the `diagLabel` column, i.e. the one with `mapping: label = ~diagLabel` which for your case is the third.

```r
library(GGally)

p <- ggcorr(ex_db,
  nbreaks = 4,
  label = TRUE,
  label_size = 3,
  method = c("pairwise", "spearman")
)
p$layers[[3]]$data[c("diagLabel")] <- names(ex_db)

p
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
ex_db <- structure(list(
  SAPS = c(
    11L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 13L,
    12L, 15L
  ),
  `e'` = c(119, 62, 74, 75, 111, 66, 102, 71, 100, 108),
  `E/e'` = c(50, 111, 82, 68, 78, 105, 60, 91, 61, 49)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I already filed an issue on that: https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/465